# Can't access resources in kotlin from src/main/resources

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I have a gradle kotlin project , where I want to load a file from my resources directory.
My kotlin classes are in src/main/kotlin/packagenames and my resources are in src/main/resources

After gradle build including kotlin plugin (kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.20") my classes are copied to build/classes/kotlin/main/packagenames and my resources to build/resources/main

Now I try to read this files from my kotlin code

```
object {}.javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/resources/filename")
```

or

```
object {}.javaClass.classloader.getResourceAsStream("/resources/filename")
```

but the files are not found.

When I try to see which directory it looks into

```
println(this.javaClass.getResource("/"))
```

results in build/classes/kotlin and with javaClass.classLoader it returns null accessing '/'

This means normally I would have to go up two directories and then access resources directory, but this doesn't work as build/classes/kotlin seems to be the root.
Any Idea why this happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `/resources/` from the input string and instead try

```
object {}.javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/filename")
```

This should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using only R it might take material base Resource(`com.google.android.material.R.string`). so, you need to use below the code with your package name Resource(`com.example.app.R.string`)

```kotlin
textView.text = getString(com.example.app.R.string.app_name)
```